How to relate Message Sent Event, Message Delivered Event, Message Read Event received on my webhook belongs to the which sent message of mine
I am currently doing a POC with whatsapp cloud API. I am currently able to send the messages through my business account and i do get the below events back to my webhook from meta i.e

Message Sent Event
Message Delivered Event
Message Read Event

My question is how do i know these events belong with which message of mine. I compared the payload but did not find any correlation between message i sent and these events. How do i link them?
For example i am sending multiple messages to a number and i am getting these events and i am not able to relate which events belong to which message, like mine which message is sent which one is delivered and which one is read. Can anyone help or point me to some resource.
And also by default do we have any dashboard where we can see all the conversation happening between my business and end users. Something similar to whatsapp web
Message I Sent:
{
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "interactive": {
        "header": {
            "text": "HI, Welcome",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "action": {
            "button": "Main Menu",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "rows": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "title": "Buy"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "title": "Rent"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "type": "list",
        "body": {
            "text": "To begin, tab Main Menu and choose from one of the following options"
        }
    },
    "to": "xxxx",
    "type": "interactive"
}

Message Sent Event Received on webhook
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "xxxx",
                            "phone_number_id": "xxxx"
                        },
                        "statuses": [
                            {
                                "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE5NjQwMjI0MzU1FQIAERgSRkQ5RUJFQzRFMDVGRDJDOTc5AA==",
                                **"status": "sent",**
                                "timestamp": "1715697099",
                                "recipient_id": "xxxx",
                                "conversation": {
                                    "id": "b9c21c509cf18e204e12a8b761ee7887",
                                    "expiration_timestamp": "1715782260",
                                    "origin": {
                                        "type": "service"
                                    }
                                },
                                "pricing": {
                                    "billable": true,
                                    "pricing_model": "CBP",
                                    "category": "service"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Message Delivered Event Received on webhook
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "109319125595056",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "xxxx",
                            "phone_number_id": "xxxx"
                        },
                        "statuses": [
                            {
                                "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE5NjQwMjI0MzU1FQIAERgSRkQ5RUJFQzRFMDVGRDJDOTc5AA==",
                                **"status": "delivered",**
                                "timestamp": "1715697099",
                                "recipient_id": "xxxx",
                                "conversation": {
                                    "id": "b9c21c509cf18e204e12a8b761ee7887",
                                    "origin": {
                                        "type": "service"
                                    }
                                },
                                "pricing": {
                                    "billable": true,
                                    "pricing_model": "CBP",
                                    "category": "service"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Message Read Event Received on Webhook
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "109319125595056",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "xxxx",
                            "phone_number_id": "xxxx"
                        },
                        "statuses": [
                            {
                                "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE5NjQwMjI0MzU1FQIAERgSRkQ5RUJFQzRFMDVGRDJDOTc5AA==",
                                "status": "read",
                                "timestamp": "1715697119",
                                "recipient_id": "xxxx"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


the id received in statuses response belongs to particular message id, using this id you can update the status if messages as send,delivered,read , for understanding the webhook events refer the webhooks documetation
